# Input name and check for existence of spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create a spreadsheet if it does not exist. Name of the spreadsheet should be a user input how would I do this?

```
function createSpreadsheet() {
    var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(NewSpreadsheet);

    if (file != null) {
        var NewSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("TestGSS");
        var DataSheet = NewSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Data");
        // Get the URL of the document.
        var url = NewSpreadsheet.getUrl();

        // Get the email address of the active user - that's you.
        var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    }

    Logger.log(file);

    if (DataSheet != null) {
        NewSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(DataSheet);
    }

    DataSheet = NewSpreadsheet.insertSheet();
    DataSheet.setName("Data");

    Logger.log(NewSpreadsheet.getUrl());
    Logger.log(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());

}
```

I tried doing the below for user input and check for file existence but no luck.

```
function spreadsheetName() {
    var name = Browser.inputBox('Sheet name', 'Enter spreadsheet name', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
}
```

this keeps giving me cannot call Browser.inputBox() from this context

```
function spreadsheetName() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

    Logger.log(sheet.getSheetName());
}
```

this gives cannot call getSheets method.

Comment: Where "if it does not exist"? On your Drive? On their Drives?

Comment: Well, in general could be any account which would run this function on that particular drive. To test this out I am using my authentication so it would be my drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Step 1. Implementation of the user intent

```
//Add a menu to the Spreadsheet when it's opening
function onOpen() {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
        .createMenu('Custom Menu')
        .addItem('Input New Spreadsheet Name', 'spreadsheetName')
        .addToUi();
}
```

#### Step 2. Realise your actions

```
function spreadsheetName() {
    var name = Browser.inputBox('Sheet name', 'Enter spreadsheet name', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
    if (name == 'cancel') return;
    // do more with your ideas  and `name` value below
    //Something like this
    createSpreadsheet(name);
}
```

#### Additionals

I look at your code and see two `spreadsheetName()` functions. Are you use their into the namespace? GS doesn't show an exeption and takes one of their.

There is a method to check if a file exists

```
function checkFileExistByName(name) {
    var fileIterator = DriveApp.getFilesByName(name);
    return fileIterator.hasNext();
}
```

Comment: Hi Alexander, Thanks very much for your response. I still get "cannot call Browser.inputBox() from this context" error. Could you please guide me.